# build release configuration for sqlite wp8 app

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8

i am trying to build a release configurarion of my app using sqlite on ARM for open store test kit platform but it gives the error namespace community not found . How can i fix this and publish my app

Answer (score 1):

The SQLite-net nuget package requires you have the conditional constant USE_WP8_NATIVE_SQLITE set in the projects properties otherwise you get that error.

Comment: i have already done that both in debug and release mode . Still i get that error